# Does handwriting recognition require mobile data?

Tags: ios, apple-pencil, handwriting

I gather that scribble now allows handwriting recognition in any iOS app. Does it require mobile data or is everything on-device? (I do not yet have an Apple Pencil so cannot test this for myself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The handwriting recognition done by Scribble is performed on-device. There's no need for a mobile data connection to a cloud service in order to perform the actual recognition.

However, you will at some points need an internet connection to download the Scribble system itself (unless your iPad was acquired a new iOS version that already has this feature).

Comment: As a general rule, Apple is very proud of the fact that they never send any sensitive, personal, or biometric data into the cloud, unless it is for the express reason of storing it there. Voice rec, facial rec, handwriting, etc. is all done on-device. That's why they have added those powerful DSPs and machine learning / neural network / AI cores to all of their CPUs, both the mobile Axyz line and the desktop M1s.